# XenServer 7.5 Virtual Machines not booting without installation media

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen, hardware-virtualization, xenserver

I recently turned an old gaming computer into a server and decided to put XenServer 7.5 on so I could flip between Windows and Linux servers. Installation of the hypervisor went well and I proceeded to setup a Windows 10 virtual machine. I installed some basic programs, then shut it down for the night.

I removed the Windows installation disk before shutting the server down, thinking I was done with it.

When I tried to start the VM later, I got the error message -

```
Unable to attach empty optical drive to VM.
```

The VM failed to start. I thought that it was a Windows issue and spent a full day attempting to debug it by reinstalling Windows and setting up a second VM to try and reinstall properly.

Last night I tried to do the same thing with a Fedora Linux disk I had lying around.  OS setup went well.  Remove installation disk, then the VM won't boot.

Both VMs boot fine when I still have the installation disks in, and changes are saved between sessions.

In addition, trying to start the VMs from the server console gives the error:

```
Failed: SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_456
```

TL;DR: VMs on my XenServer won't boot without their original installation media.